# Q: Android - BroadcastListener for Setting change - Is there a better way than this?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

**Specifically, I want my BroadcastListener to fire some code when the 'Location' Setting gets turned 'ON'.**

Please, can anyone provide a **simpler and more direct way** to do this, compared to my current logic (below)?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    LocationManager locationManager = 
        (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    boolean isGpsEnabled;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled;


    isGpsEnabled = 
        locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnabled = 
        locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

        if (isGpsEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) {

            // FIRE CODE HERE FOR WHEN LOCATION SETTING TURNS "ON"
        }

    }
}
```

And then in the Manifest I have:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

..Certainly there is a better way, but that's what I came up with so far. Still learning..

Again, I just need to respond to when the 'Location' Setting gets turned 'ON' - but **I cant seem to find a way to identify the entire Location Setting in general..**

**If anybody would please help me with a better way to do this, I would greatly appreciate it!**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post also the code inside in the if-else statement. Because I have a bad feeling of your `(isGpsEnabled || isNetworkEnabled)`

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to change about my logic! I want to somehow replace the "gps location OR network location" specifics with simply "the entire location setting in general being turned on"..